# Linq - pulling a value from a null query result

Tags: linq-to-sql, lambda

I have a linq query that needs to pull a date column out of a row. The expression currently looks like this

```
myObject.OrderByDescending(s=> s.MyDate).Where(s => s.CRAStatus.Description == "CheckedOut").FirstOrDefault().MyDate)
```

The problem is that if there are no rows that are "CheckedOut", the query will return a null and attempting to get "MyDate" will throw an exception. We have some verbose solutions, like:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.CheckOutDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => {
    var temp = src.CRAStatusChangeEvents.OrderByDescending(s=> s.MyDate).Where(s => s.CRAStatus.Description == "CheckedOut").FirstOrDefault();
    return temp == null ? temp.MyDate : null;
}));
```

But it would be nice to find something a little more concise. Any Ideas?

Comment: +1: always good to see folks wanting to be concise for maintainability and readability in code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not

```
myObject.OrderByDescending(s=> s.MyDate)
        .Where(s => s.CRAStatus.Description == "CheckedOut")
        .Select(s => s.MyDate as DateTime?)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
myObject.Where(s => s.CRAStatus.Description == "CheckedOut")
        .Max(s => s.MyDate as DateTime?);
```

Comment: don't forget "as DateTime?", if you don't add that, you'll still get a NRE.

Comment: That is very nice! Thanks Ruben!

Comment: In my case anyway "as DateTime?) isn't even needed so it's even more terse. Great job.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to set the [default if empty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) to an "empty" instance (think of string.Empty--its a known instance that represents an empty result):

```
var date = (myObject
    .OrderByDescending(s=> s.MyDate)
    .Where(s => s.CRAStatus.Description == "CheckedOut")
    .DefaultIfEmpty(MyObject.Empty)
    .FirstOrDefault()).MyDate;
```

Here's a snippet that shows how it works:

```
var strings = new string[]{"one", "two"};
var length = 
    (strings.Where(s=>s.Length > 5)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty)
    .FirstOrDefault()).Length;
```

run that and length is 0.  Remove the DefaultIfEmpty line and you get a NRE.

Comment: It was a happy, happy day when I found that method.  Damn, my life is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
var checkedOut = myObject.Where(s => s.CRAStatus.Description == "CheckedOut");
if (checkedOut.Count() > 0) {
   var result = checkedOut.Max(s=> s.MyDate).MyDate;
}
```

Comment: you can replace checkedOut.Count > 0 with !checkedOut.Empty() for better readability

Comment: I'm afraid you can't in this case. IEnumerable<typeof(myObject)>

Answer (score 1):

How about an extension method?

```
static class MyObjectEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static TMember GetMemberOfFirstOrDefault<TMember>(this IEnumerable<MyObject> items, Func<MyObject, TMember> getMember)
    {
        MyObject first = items.FirstOrDefault();
        if (first != null)
        {
            return getMember(first);
        }
        else
        {
            return default(TMember);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
List<MyObject> objects = new List<MyObject>();
objects.Add(new MyObject { MyDate = DateTime.MinValue });

var filteredObjects = from s in objects where s.MyDate > DateTime.MinValue select s;

DateTime date = filteredObjects.GetMemberOfFirstOrDefault(s => s.MyDate);

Console.WriteLine(date);
```